# Is it possible for an android application to use permissions that are not declared in the manifest.xml file?

Tags: android, permissions, android-manifest, android-permissions

I'm reading a paper, and it says this：

----------paper text----------

four sets of permissions for each app, namely

1.Declared permissions, i.e., permissions declared in the Android Manifest file;

2.Exploited permissions, i.e., permissions that are actually exploited in the app code;

3.Ghost permissions, i.e., permissions that the app tries to exploit in the code, but they are not declared in the Android Manifest file;

4.Useless permissions, i.e., declared permissions that are not exploitedin the app code.

----------end----------

I'm really confused with the third permissions--'Ghost permissions'. As far as I know, all the permissions that android will use must be declared in the Manifest.xml, so how can we use permissions that are not declared in the Manifest, or that is wrong?
Here's a link to the paper:
https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-58469-0_36 
The excerpt is on page 5.

Comment: Android is not allowed to use undeclared permission in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: Yes, I think so. But why is that in the paper? It should be an obvious mistake. Is there any special case?